# Guitar Pro 5 tab not playing last bar

Tags: guitar-pro

*[image: emphasized text]*I have a Guitar Pro 5 tab which only plays 17 bars then stops.

Not just with Tux but all other players.

How do I change GP5 so it plays all 18 bars?

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that the volta bracket in bar 18 is numbered as "2.", but should be "1.".

This might cause an error which stops the song when playing.

Comment: That worked - brilliant - had to go onto my pc to correct it though.

Comment: @Msannetteelmore Glad I could help :) Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, if it solved your problem.

Comment: How do i do that!

Comment: @Msannetteelmore Next to each question and answer are up- and down- arrows that allow you to up- or downvote them. In addition, the answers below your own question have a little "check" symbol next to those arrows. If you click it, the answer is set to "accepted" and your question is solved. See this [help site](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more details.